# cocos2d-js cocostudio "Illegal buffer" error

Tags: cocos2d-js, cocostudio

```
var node = ccs.csLoader.createNode("res/some_cocostudio_file.csb");
```

```
Cocos2d-JS v3.1
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal buffer
```

I'm tried csb files from js-tests - same result... But js-tests run well...

Answer (score 0):

Please be a little more patient, Cocos2d-JS v3.3 will provide full support for Cocos Studio 2.x. v3.1 do have some issues with the parser.

The v3.3 beta will be released the 23rd January, please stay tuned on our forum: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/category/cocos2d-x/javascript